# ClojureScript optimized compilation requires goog.net.EventType declaration in externs file

Tags: compilation, clojurescript

The IFrameIo Clojure Library (https://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/docs/class_goog_net_IframeIo.html) can be used to facilitate file uploads. One of the more important pieces of the upload process is the event listener that dispatches the success callback once the file has successfully been uploaded:

```
(goog.events/listen (IframeIo.) (aget goog.net.EventType "SUCCESS") #(success-callback))
```

This works fine in a local development environment. However, as soon as the code is deployed to a production environment, the success-callback is no longer invoked, even if the upload is successful. After some investigation, it became clear that the compilation process was mangling the keys of the goog.net.EventType object:

Expected:

```
Object { SUCCESS: function() ..., ERROR: function() ...}
```

Actual:

```
Object { az: function() ..., of: function() ...}
```

The only way to resolve the issue was to create an externs file dependency that would prevent the object from being mangled:

in project.clj:

```
{:prod
  {:compiler
    {:optimizations :advanced
     :pretty-print false
     :externs ["path/to/googNet-EventType.js"]}}}
```

googNet-EventType.js:

```
var goog = {}
goog.net = {}
goog.net.EventType = {}
goog.net.EventType.SUCCESS
```

The compilation process now preserves the SUCCESS attribute of the goog.net.EventType object, thus successfully invoking the callback.

Why is it that a dependency from goog.net would mangle it's own objects?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need externs for this case. Your interaction with Google Closure Library is the cause of the problem. Google Closure Library enums are also subject to minification:

```
(goog.events/listen (IframeIo.) 
  goog.net.EventType.SUCCESS #(success-callback))
```

Is what you want. I would personally use the `ns` form to alias `goog.events` to `gevents` and import `EventType` so I could write:

```
(gevents/listen (IframeIo.) 
  EventType.SUCCESS #(success-callback))
```

You really should never use `aget` to access an Object property when using property syntax will do. If for some reason you do need to look up a property by string use `goog.object.get`.